# How to create drop-down lists and randomly show one of the items chosen?

Tags: php, html, random

There are 4 text boxes existing in the piece of code below. You can type everything you want within these four text boxes and when you click the "Pick one" button, you will get back the text you've entered within the text boxes. But I would like to change these text boxes to drop-down lists from which you can select four different teams and when you click the "Pick one" button, randomly, you will get one of the four teams you've chosen.

```
<?php

error_reporting(0);

if(isset($_POST['submit']))
    {
        $team1=$_POST['team1'];
        $team2=$_POST['team2'];
        $team3=$_POST['team3'];
        $team4=$_POST['team4'];

        $teams=array
        (
            "1" =>"$team1",
            "2" =>"$team2",
            "3" =>"$team3",
            "4" =>"$team4",
        );
    $random = rand(1, 4);
    }
?>


<html>
<form action="index.php" method="POST">
Enter the team name<input type="text" name="team1" value="<?php echo $team1 ?>"><br>
Enter the team name<input type="text" name="team2" value="<?php echo $team2 ?>"><br>
Enter the team name<input type="text" name="team3" value="<?php echo $team3 ?>"><br>
Enter the team name<input type="text" name="team4" value="<?php echo $team4 ?>"><p>

<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Pick One!"><br>
</form>

<?php

print $teams["$random"];

?>
</html>
```

Comment: It is not clear what your actual question is here now. Where/how does this have anything to do with a dropdown menu?

Comment: sorry,i try to explain better.So right now,there is 4  input text place.You can write everything what you want and when you click the "pick one" button, you gonna get back any text what you entered earlier.
I would like change these kind of input text places to the dropdown lists where you can select some teams and when you click "pick one" you gonna get 1 team randomly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want use drop-down lists instead of text boxes, you can use the piece of code below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

    <form action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);?>" method="post">

        <label for="select1">Team 1: </label>
        <select name="team1" id="select1">
            <option>TeamName1</option>
            <option>TeamName2</option>
            ...
        </select><br/>

        <label for="select2">Team 2: </label>
        <select name="team2" id="select2">
            <option>TeamName1</option>
            <option>TeamName2</option>
            ...
        </select><br/>

        <label for="select3">Team 3: </label>
        <select name="team3" id="select3">
            <option>TeamName1</option>
            <option>TeamName2</option>
            ...
        </select><br/>

        <label for="select4">Team 4: </label>
        <select name="team4" id="select4">
            <option>TeamName1</option>
            <option>TeamName2</option>
            ...
        </select><br/>

        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">

    </form>

<?php

    if (!empty($_POST['submit'])) {

        $randnumber = rand(1, 4);

        echo $_POST['team' . $randnumber];

    }

?>

</body>
</html>
```

I hope my answer will be useful for you

Comment: unfortunately,i get error message when i try to put more option tag.The error message is:"Undefined index"(exatly lines:48 and 55) So there is someting wrong with for and rand.I try to enlarge it,but still working badly.

Comment: @Santiago so sorry me about that. It was my fault. I just edited the piece of code above so if you use it now, there will be no problem.

Comment: i dont want to disturb you such a small problem but this still working badly.When i try to enlarge i got an error code which is like:"Undefined offset: 4".So when right now at the options there is teamname1 and teamname2.I add teamname3, and when i get beck this(teamname 3) i get this kind of error code.I try to enlarge the rand, but i get the same error message.(Notice: Undefined offset: 4 in D:\xampp\htdocs\index.php on line 55)

Comment: @Santiago, I just changed the code. Please check it again. So sorry me about the errors you got.

Comment: right now, this is perfect.Thank you for all your efforts.